Google Sheet script to copy hyperlinked text into a new tab
The script that I’m using on GoogleSheet Appscript when moving one row to a new tab any hyperlinked text will not paste over to the new tab. How can I solve for this?
Google Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-ucJ0GmfbKIPvpwwneFVIoaM8orvAYt9NkT6m7UTDeo/edit?usp=sharing
If you look at the GoogleSheet in the leads tab I hyperlinked the word "Link" under column K. When I change the status to prospects in column A it only copies over the word text without the link attached.
Code:
function onEdit(e){
  let range = e.range;
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let val = range.getValue();
  let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if (col == 1 && val != '') {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());
    let data = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(val);
    targetSheet.appendRow(data[0]);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}


I followed a couple of tutorials via Youtube and even tried chatGPT for help but no success. Feel free to look at the googlesheet itself.

Try this:
function onEdit(e){
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  let sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value) {    
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(e.value);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}


Range.copyTo()

